# How do I render MVC code in a string on my page?

Tags: c#, html

I have an HTML string that also contains a call to a partial view
When I render the string as such, it renders the HTML but not the Partial View.

My Partial file has the text **Welcome to my Partial!**

```
@Model.MyText = "This is my Text @Html.Partial('Partials/Partial') Done!";
@Html.Raw(Model.MyText)
```

Renders:

```
This is my Text @Html.Partial('Partials/Partial') Done!
```

Instead of:

```
This is my Text. Welcome to my Partial! Done!
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The razor snippet only works in the context of the .csharp file itself, not the rendered webpage. When you call `@Html.Raw(Model.MyText)`, it **correctly** renders the string as html. However the resulting html is not parsed as C# code, it is just a string of text. This is not the way to achieve your desired result.
Everything you need done using C# must be done before the render. After rendering, its just html code/text.